# How to publish youtube video to wall of facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wanted to publish youtube video to wall of facebook.Does any one know ,how to do that.If yes,let me know that.

Comment: Why not check the facebook API? I'm sure there is something at least similar there.

Comment: you'd be surprised but their documentation is sh*t

Answer (score 0):

well i use involver

http://www.involver.com/

to publish vids from youtube to my fb page but it doesn't work on personal facebook wall

you can press the share button under the youtube video and share it to facebook and it will be published on your wall, you can also copy the link and past it on facebook wall

Comment: I am asking through graph or any other api(coding).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/) is a very good start. It explains how to publish using GraphAPI.
You'll need an app ( [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) ) and you'll need to :

Get the app linked to your account with permissions ( publish_stream for publishing on a User's wall ) echoing some javascript to reload the page to facebook with a redirect_uri to your app or your web page.

```
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&scope=publish_stream";
   echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

Get the token via

```
   $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
       . "&code=" . $code;
   $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

Then you'll need to send a post with enctype="multipart/form-data" to https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos? with the following elements:

1. token
2. description
3. title
4. file ( as a multipart upload stream )

using a form like:

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $my_url ?>" method="POST">
       <input type="file" name="file>
       <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

The main drawback is that after you successfully uploaded ( or not ) you'll have a plain json with either the error code or the Object Graph ID of the newly created element. I haven't sorted out yet how to overcome that. I'll try CURL out.